# How do you exit an interrupt routine and go back to main?

Tags: c

I'm using Tiva C Series board with Keil uVision IDE. I'm basically trying to do the following using interrupts:

If Switch 1 & Switch 2 are not pressed: flash red LED.
If Switch 1 is pressed, enter interrupt routine and flash green LED.

Once Switch 1 is released, reenter main to continue flashing red LED.

The interrupt service routine is entered on a falling-edge trigger. I know I need to somehow go back to main on the rising-edge trigger, however I am unsure how to do this.

I tried to comment the best I could, so here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "Final Project.h"
#include "inc/hw_types.h"
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "inc/hw_gpio.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "driverlib/pin_map.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"

#include "inc/tm4c123gh6pm.h"       // manually added by the programmer
#include "driverlib/interrupt.h"    // manually added by the programmer


// Interrupt handler
void GPIOPortF_Handler(void)
    {
        // acknowledge flag for PF0
        GPIO_PORTF_ICR_R |= 0x01;   

        // Switch 1 is pressed
        if(GPIOPinRead(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4)==0x00)
        {
            // turn off red LED
            GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R &= ~0x02;
            // turn off blue LED
            GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R &= ~0x04;

            // while switch 1 is pressed
            while(GPIOPinRead(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4)==0x00)
            {
                // Turn on green LED
                GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R |= 0x08;
                // Delay
                SysCtlDelay(16000000/3/2);
                // Turn off green LED
                GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R &= ~0x08;
                // Delay
                SysCtlDelay(16000000/3/2);
            }
        }
    }

    void Interrupt_Init(void)
{
    NVIC_EN0_R |= 0x40000000;           // enable interrupt 30 in NVIC (GPIOF)
    NVIC_PRI7_R &= ~0x00E00000;     // configure GPIOF interru  
    GPIO_PORTF_IM_R |= 0x01;            // arm interrupt on PF0
    GPIO_PORTF_IS_R &= ~0x01;           // PF0 is edge-sensitive
    GPIO_PORTF_IBE_R |= 0x01;           // PF0 both edges trigger
    //GPIO_PORTF_IEV_R &= ~0x01;    // PF0 falling edge event
    //IntGlobalEnable();                    // Globally enable interrupt (without PinMux)
    IntMasterEnable();                      // Globally enable interrupt (with PinMux)
}


void
PortFunctionInit(void)
{
    // Enable Peripheral Clocks 
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOD);
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOF);

    // Enable pin PD1 for GPIOInput
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1);

    // Enable pin PD0 for GPIOOutput
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0);

    // Enable pin PF2 for GPIOOutput
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2);

    // Enable pin PF3 for GPIOOutput
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3);

    // Enable pin PF0 for GPIOInput
        GPIO_PORTF_PUR_R |= 0x01; 

    // Enable pin PF4 for GPIOInput
        GPIO_PORTF_PUR_R |= 0x10; 

    //First open the lock and select the bits we want to modify in the GPIO commit register.
    HWREG(GPIO_PORTF_BASE + GPIO_O_LOCK) = GPIO_LOCK_KEY;
    HWREG(GPIO_PORTF_BASE + GPIO_O_CR) = 0x1;

    //Now modify the configuration of the pins that we unlocked.
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0);

    // Enable pin PF1 for GPIOOutput
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1);

    // Enable pin PF4 for GPIOInput
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4);
}


int main(void)
{

        // Iinitialize the GPIO ports   
        PortFunctionInit();
        // Configure the GPIOF interrupt
        Interrupt_Init();


    // Loop forever.
    while(1)
    {
            // Turn on red lED
            GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R |= 0x02;
            // Delay
            SysCtlDelay(16000000/3/2);
            // Turn off red lED
            GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R &= ~0x02;
            // Delay
            SysCtlDelay(16000000/3/2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Having a delay function in the interrupt handler `GPIOPortF_Handler` is a very bad idea.
2. Also you have a while loop in the interrupt handler waiting for user input.

The problem with the above is that the interrupt will not exit for some time. A good design ensures that the Interrupt context only runs for short time and exits. This allows for other interrupts to be registered.

I suggest that you set a volatile flag in the interrupt handler and check the flag in `main`. Based on this flag you can take appropriate actions.

Below is a simple example.

```
void GPIOPortF_Handler(void)
{
    GPIO_PORTF_ICR_R |= 0x01;   
    flags = 1;
}
```

in the main function,

```
int main(void) 
{
    while(1) 
    {   
        if(flags==1)
        { 
            GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R |= 0x02; 
            SysCtlDelay(16000000/4); 
            GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R &= ~0x02; 
            SysCtlDelay(16000000/4); 
        } 
        else
        { 
            // Turn on red lED
            GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R |= 0x02;
            // Delay
            SysCtlDelay(16000000/4);
            // Turn off red lED
            GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R &= ~0x02;
            // Delay
            SysCtlDelay(16000000/4);
        }

        /* Check status of switch */
        if ( /* enter switch port here */ == 0)
        {
            GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R &= ~0x02; /* make green LED OFF */
            flags = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this example does have some drawbacks, and will take some time to detect the key. Based on the time `SysCtlDelay` it may be acceptable.

Comment: Thank you. In my interrupt handler when switch 1 is pressed, flags = 1. In main, I have if(flags==1){**flash green LED**}. I can enter the interrupt handler, but I'm still not sure how to return back to the main function. How do you suggest I proceed?

Comment: You should do all your processing in the main function. The interrupt handler should run for very short time (in the order of 10's or 100's of microseconds). You will never know when the interrupt occurs, but in the main loop, you will see the flag as 1.

Comment: That makes sense. How would I go about making the interrupt handler run for a very short time? I understand that setting flags = 1 will keep the interrupt handler on for the duration of the program, but I'm unsure of a different way to make the interrupt handler run for a shorter time. My apologies for my lack of programming skills.

Comment: As mentioned in the original answer, remove delay functions and blocking loops from IRQ handlers. Then the handler will exit. By blocking loop, i mean loop waiting for user input. All this should be moved to the main function.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  I have done the following: void GPIOPortF_Handler(void){GPIO_PORTF_ICR_R |= 0x01; flags = 1;} and then in the main function I have the following: int main(void)
{while(1)
    { if(flags==1){
    GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R |= 0x02;
    SysCtlDelay(16000000/3/2);
    GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R &= ~0x02;
    SysCtlDelay(16000000/3/2);
   }
   if(flags!=1){
    GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R &= ~0x02;
   }

Sorry for the formatting.

Comment: For tasks like this I would recommend using a timer interrupt. Configure the timer interrupt to trigger in the time you want the LED to blink. In the interrupt handler check your Switch flag if the red or green LED is selected. This will completely remove your delay functions from the main loop and you can do other tasks there.